# Scaling a Single Column Vector of a Matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I'm interested in scaling one column of a matrix and then returning the whole matrix.

Suppose I have the matrix:

[image: matrix]

If I do something like:

```
> A[,1] * 10
```

I'll end up with:

[image]

However, I'd like to end up with something like:

[image]

Here's the solution I've come up with so far:

```
> A <- cbind(A[,1]*10, A[,2])
> A
```

Is this the best way to accomplish what I'd like to do?

Comment: If there are many columns, and you only want to change one, then `cbind(A[,1]*10, A[,-1])` might be easier

Comment: @RichardScriven, I like this a lot better than mine. Thanks for adding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign it to the columns that is being changed

```
A[,1] <- A[,1]*10
A
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   10    2
#[2,]   30    4
```

#### data

```
A <- matrix(c(1,3,2,4), ncol=2)
```